# Corruption with FileReader into FormData

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I'm building an ajax file uploader, which is possible thanks to the new [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) interface. It works if I use the original file, but if I convert the file to a binary string and then to a blob, the resulting file is corrupted. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data id=form>
      <input id=file type=file name=file>
      <button id=1>1</button>
      <button id=2>2</button>
    </form>
    <script>
      var d = document;

      function $(id) { return d.getElementById(id); };

      function xhr(fd) {
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('post', '/', true);
        x.send(fd);
      };

      $(1).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var file = $('file').files[0];
          var fd = new FormData();
          fd.append('file', file);
          xhr(fd);
        }, false
      );

      $(2).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var file = $('file').files[0];
          var fr = new FileReader();
          fr.onload = function(e) {
            var bb = new (window.BlobBuilder ||
              window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder)()
            bb.append(e.target.result);
            var b = bb.getBlob(file.type);
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', b);
            xhr(fd);
          };
          fr.readAsBinaryString(file);
        }, false
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob)
[BlobBuilder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/BlobBuilder)
[FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader)
[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)

edited to include links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working in Firefox / Chrome by converting the string into a [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays/Uint8Array):

```
var result = e.target.result;
var l = result.length
var ui8a = new Uint8Array(l)
for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
  ui8a[i] = result.charCodeAt(i);
bb.append(ui8a.buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with most of these objects, but I noticed that you reference `file.type` in the `fr.onload` function of your second event listener.  Is `file` in scope at that point?  Shouldn't you be using `e` instead?

Comment: I added some links. Yes, `file` is still in the scope; inner functions have access to the outer function's scope.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.